# Is the common cold deadly to a suppressed immune system?

Tags: medications, infection, immune-system, common-cold, virus

If you were taking an immune system suppressant such as Prograf (Tacrolimus) for a long period of time would a virus like the common cold linger in the body and cause infection over time and possibly other more serious conditions or would the immune system eventually destroy all traces of the virus but just take a longer time to do so?